# Error: Style property is not supported by native animated module

Tags: react-native

My app crashes because of this line in my code `<Animated.View style={[{ marginBottom: marginAnim }]}>` and i'm getting an error `Error: Style property 'marginBottom' is not supported by native animated module`. I have `marginAnim` in my `state` set as `marginAnim: new Animated.Value(10, { useNativeDriver: true })`. How can i apply `marginBottom` to the component `Animated.View` ?

Comment: There'a a list somewhere of which properties are and are not supported by the native driver.  Color transitions are not, but I thought margin was?  You can always just not use the native driver if it comes down to it `{ useNativeDriver: false }`.

Comment: it still crashes if i did this `marginAnim: new Animated.Value(10, { useNativeDriver: false })`. But it works if i put only `<Animated.View style={[{ marginBottom: 10 }]}>`